# paypal info not completing on live version

Tags: php, paypal

Im having difficulty with paypal, i can get it working perfectly in test mode but not in live mode....

```
 <form class="paypal-form" action=" https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">  
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">  
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="live@email.ie"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="qparcel">  
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1">  
    <input type="hidden" name="amount"  id="amount" value="<?php echo $paypal_amount; ?>">  
    <input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="0">  
    <input type="hidden" name="custom " value="<?=$orderid?>">  
    <input type="hidden" name="custom_more" value="<?php echo 'test2'; ?>">     
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">  
    <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">   
    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF">  
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/payment-complete">  
    <input type="image" src="<?php echo get_option("siteurl"); ?>/wp-content/themes/qparcel/images/pay-with-pp.jpg" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online.">  
        <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_AU/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">  
    </form>
```

RESPONSE PAGE

```
if ( isset($_POST['mc_gross']) ) {

 // do stuff

 }
```

When Im in test mode this works perfectly, in live mode it does not.

Is there a chance `$_POST['mc_gross']` doesnt appear on the live version?

Comment: `mc_gross` appears in the live version.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't really explain much here, but it looks like you're trying to use PDT and get transaction data back to your return URL..??

You just need to make sure that's all configured in your live account the same way it's configured in your test account.  Those are completely separate from each other, of course, so you have to set them up separately.